# Variables in semantically equivalent propositions (prop. logic)

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, semantics

I'm just beginning to study propositional logic myself in advance of a course I'm going to be taking on it, and I'm slightly confused by the notion of semantic equivalency (the double turnstile). What exactly do e.g. "A" and "B" in the statement A ⊨ B represent? Are they just free variables, or something else? I'm not sure how free variables can have semantic properties. Also, is semantic equivalency a relation of identity or of entailment? I've seen it referred to as "semantic entailment" but entailment and equivalency seem rather different to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are formulas; see [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence).

Comment: Sorry about beating this dead horse, but I don't think they can be formulas, they are names of formulas, I'm actually quite certain that this is the case, I assume it's common knowledge. Take an actual example: P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q. That is a shorthand for saying: "P","P⊃ Q" ⊨ "Q". It's just that most books never mention it, they simply are too lazy to use the quoting devises.

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks:

- "A" and "B" generally represent formulas. Hence, on its own, "A ⊨ B"  is a just scheme. You can fill in specific formulas to get an evaluable statement, e.g. "P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q", which is true (modus ponens), or "P ⊨ (P ∧ Q)", which is false.
- At least given standard terminology, "A" and "B" therefore are not free variables. Free variables are a matter in *predicate logic*. In propositional logic, however, there are no free variables at all.
- The double turnstile (⊨) does *not* mean semantic equivalence, but mere semantic *entailment*. So a statement of the form "A ⊨ B" means that whenever *A* is true, *B* is also true (in propositional logic, any assignment that makes *A* true also makes *B* true).
- Semantic *equivalence* means that (given two formulas A and B), both *A ⊨ B* and *B ⊨ A*. In other words, semantic equivalence means that *A* and *B* entail each other, or in propositional logic, that *A* and *B* are true under exactly the same assignments.

Comment: One should be careful here "P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q" doesn't actually make sense, if the formulas flanking "⊨" are not names but are object language sentences.

Comment: @Johannes Sorry, I don't get what you mean, can you please explain?

Comment: "P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q" is a sentence in the metalanguage, usually interpreted as expressing that the object language sentence "Q" is a consequence of the sentences "P" and "P ⊃ Q", so it has to talk about formulas hence it has to use the names of those formulas. Note that therefore in the schema "A ⊨ B" (assuming it is a schema), the schematic letters "A" and "B" take meta-language names as instances. Just like in the T-schema: "X is true iff p", this schema is expressed in the meta-meta-language, so the "X" in this schema takes as instance meta-language names of object language sentences....

Comment: @Johannes Okay, so you interpret "P" as a name for a sentence in another language (perhaps a natural language)? I think this is at least not standard; in propositional logic, "P" is already taken to be in object language. However, even if you take "P" to be in meta language, why would "P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q" not actually make sense? Of course, you will have to define "⊨" for the then-object language, but this may (for instance) be done in terms of possible worlds.

Comment: @Johannes By the way, I don't think that in the T-schema you've given, "X" is in meta-meta-language, but I see it rather as a shorthand for a name of the sentence *p*. This is because we predicate truth here, so in subject position you want to have the name of a sentence, not the name of a name of a sentence.

Comment: No you are simply wrong, it doesn't matter whether "P" is actually an object language sentence, in the context "P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q" it is part of the meta-language used as a name, ask any competetent logician, this is not often mentioned in logic texts which is bad practice. Similarly the following sentence doesn't make sense: "it's raining entails it's cloudy", that's gibberish, you have to say '"it's raining" entails "it's cloudy"'. About the T-schema it is true that its instances are in the meta-language but the schema itself is not, because "X" is a place holder for meta-language names.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, note that "P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q" is an abbreviation for saying essentially that: "whenever "P" and "P⊃ Q" are true, then "Q" is true". So "⊨" expresses an abstract relation between object language formulas, note especially the use of the truth predicate. Similarly "loves" expresses a relation between humans, so it has to take names of humans as arguments, "Aristotle loves Pythias" is well formed because it uses the names of those people as arguments, trying to put the actual people as arguments doesn't make sense, unless maybe as a strange modern art installation.

Comment: @Johannes I see, thanks for your efforts. It seems to me that you interpret "P" as *denoting* " "P" " (then indeed it is a meta-linguistic name). On the other hand, I tend to treat "P, P ⊃ Q ⊨ Q" just as a convenient shorthand for " "P", "P ⊃ Q" ⊨ "Q" ". So in the latter case, "P" is not meta language at all, is it?

Comment: Saying " "P", "P ⊃ Q" ⊨ "Q" " (without the outer quotation marks when the sentence is used) is in my view exactly correct, here " "P" " is part of the mathematician's metalanguage. So in that sentence " "P" " denotes the object language wff "P", just like the name "Aristotle" denotes the man Aristotle in "Aristotle loves Pythias". So " "P" " is used in " "P", "P ⊃ Q" ⊨ "Q" " just like "Aristotle" is used in the sentence "Aristotle loves Pythias"  both are used as names of certain objects, if I want to mention the names like I just did then I of course write " "P" " and similarly "Aristotle"